# How color specific text in shell?

Tags: shell, colors

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 26.1

Here Windows console.
Result of build my project:

```
gradlew assemble
```

here result:
[image]

as you can see text **BUILD SUCCESSFUL** is on green color.

Nice.

Now same on Emacs's shell (`M-x shell`):

[image]

Is it possible also to green color text **BUILD SUCCESSFUL** in Emacs's shell?

Comment: Which `emacs shell`? Emacs has a number of ways of interacting with shells such as bash, and has its own https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html . Is your question about how to get this particular command to show the particular bit in a particular color, or how to get selected text coloured in general?

Comment: @icarus this shell: M-x shell. How to get selected text coloured in general

Comment: If you invoke `M-x ansi-term` instead does it fix your immediate problem? The more general answer for setting a phrase to be in a color is to be found in the various `highlight-` functions. In particular `M-S h p` will prompt you for a phrase and a `face`, for the latter you can use hl-green.

Comment: @icarus no fix problem. I get error: "apply: Spawning child process: Invalid argument". Before I get message: Run program: D:/Programs/Emacs/libexec/emacs/26.1/x86_64-w64-mingw32/cmdproxy.exe

Comment: @icarus I use highlight-phrase. And it's color text BUILD SUCCESSFUL. Nice. But after reset Emacs it's not color. How color forever this text?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [xterm-color](https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color) ?

You can use the config below if you use `use-package`

```lisp
(use-package xterm-color
  :config
  (setq comint-output-filter-functions
        (remove 'ansi-color-process-output comint-output-filter-functions))

  (add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
            (lambda () (add-hook 'comint-preoutput-filter-functions
                                 'xterm-color-filter nil t))))
```

This is the output in my urxvt terminal:

[image]

This is the output of emacs shell (with xterm-color package):

[image]

Without xterm-color package it will be no color at all (in my case).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I get error: Symbol's function definition is void: use-package

Comment: I believe you didn't have `use-package`, then you can take everything inside `:config` and put it on you .emacs .

Comment: Text "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" is not color. How I can color ONLY this text in Emac's shell?